# Matching complex URLs in a string for replacement

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a long string which basically contains the whole HTML code of a page.

There are links in this page and I need to add a set of parameters at the end of these links.

Nb : All href are the same in the all page.

I managed to extract the URL in a variable with this code (html var contains my html code) :

```
var href = html.match(/href="([^"]*)/)[1];
```

Adding extra parameters :

```
var newHref = href+'&n=$ln$&p=$fn$&e=$e$';
```

I escape the first href with this function for regexp purpose :

```
function escapeRegExp(str) {
    return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|\=\%\:\&]/g,"\\$&");
}
```

Then I try to perform the replacement in the code :

```
var reCompletion = new RegExp(escapeRegExp(href),"g");
html.replace(reCompletion, newHref);
```

When I run this code it cannot find any match with the URL and perform no replacement at all.

Here is the kind of URL I have to complete :

```
http://action.mySite.com/trk.php?mclic=P4CAB9542D7F151&urlrv=http%3A%2F%2Fjeu-centerparcs.com%2F%23%21%2F%3Fidfrom%3D8&urlv=517b975385e89dfb8b9689e6c2b4b93d
```

Once escaped :

```
http\:\/\/action\.mySite\.com\/trk\.php\?mclic\=P4CAB9542D7F151\&urlrv\=http\%3A\%2F\%2Fjeu\-centerparcs\.com\%2F\%23\%21\%2F\%3Fidfrom\%3D8\&urlv\=517b975385e89dfb8b9689e6c2b4b93d
```

Does anyone have any clue about this ?

Comment: This API could be useful -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/72720886/17519455

Comment: This API could solve your problem -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/72720886/17519455

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `$` symbols in the replacement part: the dollars must be doubled to be replaced with 1 `$`:

```
var newHref = (href+'&n=$ln$&p=$fn$&e=$e$').replace(/\$/g, '$$$$');
```

Also, remove unnecessary escaping symbols from `escapeRegExp`:

```
function escapeRegExp(str) {
    return str.replace(/[-[\]\/{}()*+?.\\^$|=%:&]/g,"\\$&");
}
```

Here is  a snippet:

```js
var html = "More here http://action.mySite.com/trk.php?mclic=P4CAB9542D7F151&urlrv=http%3A%2F%2Fjeu-centerparcs.com%2F%23%21%2F%3Fidfrom%3D8&urlv=517b975385e89dfb8b9689e6c2b4b93d text<br/>And more here http://action.mySite.com/trk.php?mclic=P4CAB9542D7F151&urlrv=http%3A%2F%2Fjeu-centerparcs.com%2F%23%21%2F%3Fidfrom%3D8&urlv=517b975385e89dfb8b9689e6c2b4b93d";
var href = "http://action.mySite.com/trk.php?mclic=P4CAB9542D7F151&urlrv=http%3A%2F%2Fjeu-centerparcs.com%2F%23%21%2F%3Fidfrom%3D8&urlv=517b975385e89dfb8b9689e6c2b4b93d";
var newHref = (href+'&n=$ln$&p=$fn$&e=$e$').replace(/\$/g, '$$$$');
function escapeRegExp(str) {
    return str.replace(/[-[\]\/{}()*+?.\\^$|=%:&]/g,"\\$&");
}
var reCompletion = new RegExp(escapeRegExp(href),"g");
html = html.replace(reCompletion, newHref);
document.body.innerHTML = html;
```