# How to extract urls from a string that doesn't contain https or www

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, string, url

Consider a string

```
let a =  "I visit google.com often times but.. not amazon.uk"
```

How to extract google.com and amazon.uk from the string above in JavaScript

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}` might do the trick for most sites. but i strongly against this kind of approach only - its very inaccurate. you should try to capture the second group and test it against [known list of tld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains). also, if you take a look on the rfc (forgot the exact number) for domain names, you will find that entire unicode (non-modern latin alphabet) is valid. cmiiw.

Comment: this [QA regarding regex for capturing url](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3809401) is a nice start. it would be best if you could: 1) check valid tlds; 2) check if the actual site is on DNS record.

Comment: added a solution, does it address your question?

Comment: @Naveed Thanks for your solution but it solves only if there is .com or .uk I want to take all the urls even if it contains some other domain extension

Comment: @Lahfir, you an add those domains here delimited with the pipe and it will work (.uk|.com).

Comment: we would either needs to know a pattern to identify these as domains or a list of the domains we want to search. the Solution presented with work when you have a list of domains already identified and answers the question from that standpoint

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
let a =  "I visit google.com often times but.. not amazon.uk"
a.match(/("[^"]+"|[^"\s]+)/g);
```

Output:

```
[
    "I",
    "visit",
    "google.com",
    "often",
    "times",
    "but..",
    "not",
    "amazon.uk"
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what if there is a domain with some other extension .io or something? Do you suggest to store the list of extensions in an array and compare with that?

Comment: I think you need write a custom parser for it

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it

\s(\w+)(.uk|.com)\b

here is a fiddle link for Javascript

```
https://jsfiddle.net/y25wz3ae/
```

[image]

```
https://regex101.com/r/HFyxEJ/1
```

Result
[('google', '.com'), ('amazon', '.uk')]

Answer (score -1):

To solve this problem I've created an API to extract URLs from a string or an array of strings

Base Url -> https://urlsparser.herokuapp.com/

GET https://urlsparser.herokuapp.com/url

**For a single string**

```
{
  "string" : "More here http://action.mySite.com/trk.php?mclic=P4CAB9542D7F151&urlrv=http%3A%2F%2Fjeu-centerparcs.com%2F%23%21%2F%3Fidfrom%3D8&urlv=517b975385e89dfb8b9689e6c2b4b93d text<br/>And more here http://action.mySite.com/trk.php?mclic=P4CAB9542D7F151&urlrv=http%3A%2F%2Fjeu-centerparcs.com%2F%23%21%2F%3Fidfrom%3D8&urlv=517b975385e89dfb8b9689e6c2b4b93d"
}
```

**For an array of strings**

```
{
  "string" : ["string1","string2"....]
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image: 2]

**Advantages**

1. Has more than 900 domain extensions [.com,.io,....]
2. Faster, extracts result in less than 20ms